# Files not getting transferred from Windows to Linux remote server

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to use WinSCP in visual studio. I downloaded and installed WinSCP using the Managed NuGet package. I have used the below code in a web application to transfer one of the files to a remote Linux server. The code executes fine without any error, but the file is not transferred. I logged in using PuTTY to verify if the file has actually transferred, but could not locate the file. Below is the code used

```
public int Upload(String HostName, String UserName, String Password, String remotePath, String localFilePath)
{
    int result = 0;
    Session session = null;
    try
    {
        // Setup session options               
        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
            HostName = HostName,
            UserName = UserName,
            Password = Password,
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),

        };

        using (session = new Session())
        {
            // Connect
            session.Open(sessionOptions);

            // upload files
            TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
            transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Ascii;

            TransferOperationResult transferResult = null;
            transferResult = session.PutFiles(localFilePath, remotePath, false, transferOptions);

            //  Throw on any error
            transferResult.Check();
            //  Print results
            foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName);
            }
            session.GetFiles(@"\\remoteserver\folder1\folder_backups\test_files\test1.txt", @"d:\folder3\").Check();
        }

        result = 0;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
        result = 1;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (session != null)
        {
            session.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The arguments are passed as below:

```
project1.Upload("remote host server", "username", "password", @"\\remote host server\folder1\folder_backups\test_files\", Fileupload1.PostedFile.FileName);
```

The code executes without any error, but no file is uploaded nor downloaded. How to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Please post WinSCP session log file (`Session.SessionLogPath`).

Comment: `\\remote host server\folder1\folder_backups\test_files\ ` does not really look like a valid FTP path. What path do you see in WinSCP GUI, when you login to the server?

Comment: session.sessionLogpath is null

Comment: You have to set `Session.SessionLogPath` to a path, where you want to store the session log file to! ---- And you didn't answer my other question. - What path do you see in WinSCP GUI file panel, after you *"navigate to folders"* (as you wrote in a comment to the other question)?

Comment: After the login happens in GUI - it points to /home/UserId  . But the folder which i want to move the files exist in /folder1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After the login happens in GUI - it points to /home/UserId . But the folder which i want to move the files exist in /folder1

If remote path you want to use is `/folder1/`, use that for `remotePath` argument of your `Upload` method, instead of obviously wrong value `@"\\remote host server\folder1\folder_backups\test_files\"`.

```
project1.Upload("host", "user", "password", "/folder1/", Fileupload1.PostedFile.FileName);
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it. Getting error as Error transferring file 'C:\Users\userID\Desktop\change1.txt'.
Copying files to remote side failed.
Could not create file.


{WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: Error transferring file 'C:\Users\userId\Desktop\change1.txt'.
Copying files to remote side failed.
Could not create file.
   at WinSCP.OperationResultBase.Check()

Comment: So again, show us a session log file. + A log file from WinSCP GUI showing upload of the same file to the same remote directory would help too.

Comment: Found the issue. The last '/' is required after the folder name

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure but looks like you've set the protocol to FTP which may not be supported by the server. If you're able to login via putty then that means SSH connection is possible. Try setting the protocol to SFTP.

Comment: If FTP protocol was not supported, the `Open` method would throw. Though you are right with the SFTP.

Comment: with WinSCP GUI, it is connecting through FTP. The folders which I am trying to access is in the root path. By default, when the connection is established through code, it is navigating to my user id folder. I need to go back to root directory and then navigate to folders. How to go back to root directory through code